# history.pushState ajax content, not re-running js on $.get data

Tags: javascript, html

/Editted//

I am trying to make my webapp have a nice loading animation between pages, and to quickly fetch them. It breaks the second time when I click a link. It feels as if the script only allows itself to be run on the original content, and not the newly loaded remote content. Or it might be that it only is working once, on the first link and back button. I can't figure it out.

```
////////////// Change page function ///////////////////
function changePage(href){
    $('div#pre-loader').removeClass('hide');
    $('.page-content').addClass('hide');
    var newHref = href.replace(site_url, site_url+'/data');
    $.get(newHref, function(data){
        $('div.page-content').replaceWith(data);
        $('div#pre-loader').addClass('hide');
    });
}

///////////Link click///////////
$('a').click(function(e){
    if (Modernizr.history){
        if($(this).hasClass("internal-link")){
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            history.pushState(null, null, href);
            changePage(href);
        }
    }
});
//////////// Back button ////////////
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    newHref = site_url + location.pathname;
    changePage(newHref);
});
```

When I add in the /data/ part to the url my server only returns what's inside the page-content div, and it isn't hidden anymore.

**EDIT**
Realized the issue, it seems that the js which I have already loaded(in app.js, where the above code is) is not running on the newly loaded content. This would be because I leave all my CSS and JS files intact, and only load the content(with the extra /data/). Now I have tried googling and searching all through SO, and nowhere does it seem to address the issue. Is there any simple script which i can include in all the /data/ files which will reload the js, or is there a way in which i can make my scripts automatically run on new content?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/1233508).

Comment: Changed code to this: http://pastebin.com/GuXRC4Nx and nothing has changed....

Comment: You misunderstood the answer. The key point is that the answers in that question use three arguments for `on`, not two like your code does.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I didn't need 3 functions...all i needed to do was change $('a').on('click',function(e){}) to $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){}